# Simplify JQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**NOTE**:  I added this to a JSFIDDLE found at [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/kbarrows/SWEvm/1/)

---

I've written some basic jQuery code to manipulate rows from one of 3 tables, handle a couple button clicks and checkboxes.  I feel so much like a n00b right now.  I am looking at this and realize that there is so much that could be turned into more generic functions, but am not versed with creating JS functions.  Any pointers would be welcome.

Since I have blocks of like functionality, I would prefer to discuss how to simplify each block type.

- buttonSwap
- Select/deselct check list
- Move check list
- Show/hide panels

Here is the code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#displayActivePanel').hide();
        $('#displayInactivePanel').hide();

        // Button event handlers to move items from/to differing tables...
        $('#TableAdminPortfolio tbody .buttonSwap').live('click', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var stat = tr.children('.padLeft.status').text().trim();
            var tableActiveProjects = $('#TableActiveProjects tbody');
            var tableInactiveProjects = $('#TableInactiveProjects tbody');

            tr.fadeOut(1000);
            if (stat == 'Active') {
                tableActiveProjects.prepend(tr);
            } else {
                tableInactiveProjects.prepend(tr);
            }
            tr.fadeIn(1000);
        });

        $('#TableActiveProjects tbody .buttonSwap').live('click', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var tableAdminPortfolio = $('#TableAdminPortfolio tbody');

            tr.fadeOut(1000);
            tableAdminPortfolio.prepend(tr);
            tr.fadeIn(1000);
        });

        $('#TableInactiveProjects tbody .buttonSwap').live('click', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var tableAdminPortfolio = $('#TableAdminPortfolio tbody');

            tr.fadeOut(1000);
            tableAdminPortfolio.prepend(tr);
            tr.fadeIn(1000);
        });

        $('#masterCheckBoxAdminPortfolio').live('change', function () {
            var isChecked = $('#masterCheckBoxAdminPortfolio:checked').val() != undefined;

            var list = $('#TableAdminPortfolio .CheckBoxProjects');
            list.each(function () {
                this.checked = isChecked;
            });
        });
        $('#TableActiveProjectsCheckbox').live('change', function () {
            var isChecked = $('#TableActiveProjectsCheckbox:checked').val() != undefined;

            var list = $('#TableActiveProjects .CheckBoxProjects');
            list.each(function () {
                this.checked = isChecked;
            });
        });
        $('#TableInactiveProjectsCheckbox').live('change', function () {
            var isChecked = $('#TableInactiveProjectsCheckbox:checked').val() != undefined;

            var list = $('#TableInactiveProjects .CheckBoxProjects');
            list.each(function () {
                this.checked = isChecked;
            });
        });

        $('#TableAdminPortfolioRemoveAllChecked').live('click', function () {
            var list = $('#TableAdminPortfolio .CheckBoxProjects');
            list.each(function () {
                var isChecked = $(this).closest('td').children('.CheckBoxProjects:checked').val() != undefined;
                if (isChecked) {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var stat = tr.children('.padLeft.status').text().trim();
                    var tableActiveProjects = $('#TableActiveProjects tbody');
                    var tableInactiveProjects = $('#TableInactiveProjects tbody');

                    tr.fadeOut(1000);
                    if (stat == 'Active') {
                        tableActiveProjects.prepend(tr);
                    } else {
                        tableInactiveProjects.prepend(tr);
                    }
                    tr.fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        });
        $('#TableActiveProjectsAddAllChecked').live('click', function () {
            var tableAdminPortfolio = $('#TableAdminPortfolio tbody');
            var list = $('#TableActiveProjects .CheckBoxProjects');
            list.each(function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var isChecked = $(this).closest('td').children('.CheckBoxProjects:checked').val() != undefined;
                if (isChecked) {
                    tr.fadeOut(1000);
                    tableAdminPortfolio.prepend(tr);
                    tr.fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        });
        $('#TableInactiveProjectsAddAllChecked').live('click', function () {
            var tableAdminPortfolio = $('#TableAdminPortfolio tbody');
            var list = $('#TableInactiveProjects .CheckBoxProjects');
            list.each(function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var isChecked = $(this).closest('td').children('.CheckBoxProjects:checked').val() != undefined;
                if (isChecked) {
                    tr.fadeOut(1000);
                    tableAdminPortfolio.prepend(tr);
                    tr.fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        });

        $('#showActivePanel').click(function () {
            $('#displayActivePanel').show();
        });
        $('#hideActivePanel').click(function () {
            $('#displayActivePanel').hide();
        });
        $('#showInactivePanel').click(function () {
            $('#displayInactivePanel').show();
        });
        $('#hideInactivePanel').click(function () {
            $('#displayInactivePanel').hide();
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, considering each handler does mostly different things, there isn't that much you can do to simplify this.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the html.  The showing/hiding at the bottom might be able to be moved to a toggle function instead.  If you could make a http://jsfiddle.net that would be great.

Comment: See top of question for link to jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the html, its hard to test anything at all. But this is totally winging it on the fly, just because I like a challenge and I'm bored. At the very least, it should give you a starting point for functions ... how items are passed into the function, and how the function uses those parameters.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function hideIt($item) {
    $item.hide();
}

function prependPortfolio($tr,$portfolio){
    $tr.fadeOut(1000);
    $portfolio.prepend($tr);
    $tr.fadeIn(1000);
}

function setCheck($check,$list){
    $list.each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked',$check);
    }
}

function moveItems($tr,$stat,$active,$inactive){
    $tr.fadeOut(1000);
    if ($stat == 'Active') {
        $active.prepend($tr);
    } else {
        $inactive.prepend($tr);
    }
    $tr.fadeIn(1000);
}

function addAllChecked($check,$list){
    $list.each(function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
            $check = $(this).closest('td').children('.CheckBoxProjects:checked').val() != undefined;
        if ($check) {
            prependPortfolio(tr,tableAdminPortfolio);
        }
    });
}

hideIt($('#displayActivePanel'));
hideIt($('#displayInactivePanel'));

// Button event handlers to move items from/to differing tables...
$('#TableAdminPortfolio tbody .buttonSwap').live('click', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        stat = tr.children('.padLeft.status').text().trim(),
        tableActiveProjects = $('#TableActiveProjects tbody'),
        tableInactiveProjects = $('#TableInactiveProjects tbody');

    moveItems(tr,stat,tableActiveProjects,tableInactiveProjects);
});

$('#TableActiveProjects tbody .buttonSwap').on('click', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        tableAdminPortfolio = $('#TableAdminPortfolio').find('tbody');

    prependPortfolio(tr,tableAdminPortfolio);
});

$('#TableInactiveProjects tbody .buttonSwap').on('click', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        tableAdminPortfolio = $('#TableAdminPortfolio').find('tbody');

    prependPortfolio(tr,tableAdminPortfolio);
});

$('#masterCheckBoxAdminPortfolio').on('change', function () {
    var isChecked = $('#masterCheckBoxAdminPortfolio:checked').val() != undefined,
        list = $('#TableAdminPortfolio .CheckBoxProjects');

    setCheck(isChecked,list);
});
$('#TableActiveProjectsCheckbox').on('change', function () {
    var isChecked = $('#TableActiveProjectsCheckbox:checked').val() != undefined,
        list = $('#TableActiveProjects .CheckBoxProjects');

    setCheck(isChecked,list);
});
$('#TableInactiveProjectsCheckbox').on('change', function () {
    var isChecked = $('#TableInactiveProjectsCheckbox:checked').val() != undefined,
        list = $('#TableInactiveProjects .CheckBoxProjects');

    setCheck(isChecked,list);
});

$('#TableAdminPortfolioRemoveAllChecked').on('click', function () {
    var $list = $('#TableAdminPortfolio .CheckBoxProjects');

    $list.each(function () {
        var $check = $(this).closest('td').children('.CheckBoxProjects:checked').val() != undefined;
        if ($check) {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
                stat = tr.children('.padLeft.status').text().trim(),
                tableActiveProjects = $('#TableActiveProjects tbody'),
                tableInactiveProjects = $('#TableInactiveProjects tbody');

            moveItems(tr,stat,tableActiveProjects,tableInactiveProjects);
        }
    });
});

$('#TableActiveProjectsAddAllChecked').on('click', function () {
    var tableAdminPortfolio = $('#TableAdminPortfolio tbody'),
        list = $('#TableActiveProjects .CheckBoxProjects');

    addAllChecked(tableAdminPortfolio,list);
});

$('#TableInactiveProjectsAddAllChecked').on('click', function () {
    var tableAdminPortfolio = $('#TableAdminPortfolio tbody'),
        list = $('#TableInactiveProjects .CheckBoxProjects');

    addAllChecked(tableAdminPortfolio,list);
});

$('#showActivePanel').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});

$('#showInactivePanel').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});
});
```

This should work, since I just copied and pasted and moved stuff around, but zero guarantees on that. The only things I really did that changed the way it was set up was that instead of individually declaring each variable, you can separate them by commas in one large declaration.